# How to use pagepath to get starts with only

Tags: google-analytics

I am using google analytics query to fetch data. using pagepath, I only want pages whose url begins with */xxxx/yyyy/*
when I use `pagepath=~/xxxx/yyyy/`
I am getting results like */login.aspx?r=/xxxx/yyyy/*

I don't want these, just the pages that start with my url.

Comment: this is what worked pagepath=~^/xxxx/yyyy/

Answer (score 0):

Is "google analytics query" [this page](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/)?

Did you try this:

```
pagepath=~%3D~%5E/xxxx/yyyy/.*
```

Check out [this link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference?hl=en#filters).  Search for **where the city starts with New**